# Dos - How to check Variable Name exist based on user Input?

Tags: dos

I have below batch code and I want to check when user type e.g. SB1 as input, SB1 Varialbe Name exist. In my case it does exist. But if user type SX1 then it does not exit.

```
@ECHO OFF
set "SB1=hannlsb1.mydomain.com:30515 -i 05"
set "DB1=hannlsd2.mydomain.com:31315    -i 13"
set "QB1=hannlsqa1-1:30115 -i 01"
set "DB0=hannlsd1.mydomain.com  -i 10"
set "QB0=hannlsps1-1.mydomain.com-i 03"
set "WB1=hannlsqa1-1:30315 -i 03"
set "VB1=hannlsvt-1.mydomain.com    -i 01"


@ECHO OFF
SET /P sysid=Please enter SystemID:
IF "%sysid%"=="" GOTO Error
REM ECHO Hello %sysid%, Welcome to DOS inputs!
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO You did not enter System ID! Bye bye!!
:End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `FOR /F` to run an echo command which expands the sysid into its value in the middle of an expression that then expands the value again.

```
@echo off
set "SB1=hannlsb1.mydomain.com:30515 -i 05"
set "DB1=hannlsd2.mydomain.com:31315    -i 13"
set "QB1=hannlsqa1-1:30115 -i 01"
set "DB0=hannlsd1.mydomain.com  -i 10"
set "QB0=hannlsps1-1.mydomain.com-i 03"
set "WB1=hannlsqa1-1:30315 -i 03"
set "VB1=hannlsvt-1.mydomain.com    -i 01"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /P sysid=Please enter SystemID:
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%i IN (`echo+!%sysid%!`) DO SET val=%%i
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF NOT "%val%"=="" (
   ECHO Hello %sysid%, Welcome to DOS inputs!
) ELSE (
   ECHO You did not enter System ID! Bye bye!!
)
```

Note that the delayed expansion has an unfortunate side-effect that you cannot include exclamation marks in your echo commands while it is enabled.